# A condition to a set $X$ to be a vector space

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Suppose $X$ is a set and $\mathbb{K}$ is a field, with sum operation $(x,y)\in X\times X\mapsto x+y\in X$ and multiplication operation $(\lambda, x)\in \mathbb{K}\times X\mapsto \lambda\cdot x\in X$. But we don't know any properties about these operations (for instance, we don't even know if the sum is associative).

Now, let $E$ be a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space and suppose $\phi: E\to X$ is a linear isomorphism (i.e. $\phi$ is a bijection, $\phi(u+v) = \phi(u)+\phi(v)$ and $\phi(\lambda\cdot u) = \lambda\cdot\phi(u)$, for all $u,v\in E$ and all $\lambda\in\mathbb{K}$).

My question: is this enough to assure $X$ is a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space?

Comment: Yes.  For example, commutativity of addition can be deduced from $\phi(u + v) = \phi(u) + \phi(v) = \phi(v) + \phi(u) = \phi(v + u)$ and injectivity.

Comment: Yes it's true, and I would even say that you don't need an isomorphism. A surjective linear map is enough to prove that $X$ is a vector space.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Some of you could make this comments as an answer, for it is answering my question.